# POSIX regular expression with extended syntax not matching where it should

Tags: c, regex, posix, posix-ere

I am trying to use POSIX regex in C, but it's not working. Here's my code:

```
int regi(char *c, char *e)
{
    regex_t regex;
    int reti = regcomp(&regex, e, 0);
    reti = regexec(&regex, c, 0, NULL, 0);

    if(!reti)
        return 1;

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
   char str[5] = {'0','x','2','F'};

   if(regi(str, "^(0[xX])[0-9a-fA-F]+"))
      // Do stuff

   return 0;
}
```

I was looking here: http://www.peope.net/old/regex.html

This never goes inside the if statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to use the `+` metacharacter, you need to tell `regcomp()` that you're using the [extended POSIX syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_extended):

```
int reti = regcomp(&regex, e, REG_EXTENDED);
```

There are several other problems with this code, though, including casting `const char*` to `char*`, and ignoring the return value of `regcomp()`.

Answer (score 3):

I've never quite gotten to grips with the different flavours of regexes, but I seems that [basic regexes](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html) don't know the qualifier `+`, only `*`.

One solution is to use extended regexes. You have to specify that when you compose the regex:

```
reti = regcomp(&regex, e, REG_EXTENDED);
```

(I thought that `+` could be emulated with `"\\{1,\\}"` in basic regexes, but that didn't work.)